# Sending mail with PHP. FROM function and Reply-To function not working

Tags: php

My form works and I am receiving emails from the code below. but when viewing the email, the FROM address is missing and the Reply-To is missing. the email looks like it came from nobody when i view it in my inbox. it does display everything although the code shows no errors when it is ran. I cannot see why this is happening. please could anybody help.

PHP Code

```
<?php


//Recipent

$to = $_POST['email'];

//subject

$subject = 'Thank you for joining';

//Message

$message = '<h1>Test</h1><p>Hello World</p>';

//reply to email

$reply = 'info@domain.co.uk';

//from

$from = 'noreply@domain.co.uk';

//Headers

$headers = "From " . $from . "\n";
$headers .="Reply-To: " . $reply . "\n";




//Sendmail

ini_set("sendmail_from", $from);

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f" .$from);

if($sent)
{
    
 echo'
   <script>
   window.onload = function() {
      alert("Thank you. You will receive an email confirmation shortly.");
      location.href = "index.php";  
   }
   </script>
';
    
} else {
    
    
    echo'
   <script>
   window.onload = function() {
      alert("There has been a problem. Please try again or contact us for help");
      location.href = "index.php";  
   }
   </script>
';
}


?>
```

Comment: Per the SMTP RFC, the line terminator should be `\r\n` and not just `\n`.

Comment: Thank you.  The problem still remains even with \r\n

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your codes. You need to add a colon after "From".

```
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\n";
```

It will be better you set the headers as an array.

```
$headers = array(
    'From'     => $from,
    'Reply-To' => $reply,
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);
```